# Which Firefox version is compatible with Selenium 2.42.0?

Tags: firefox, selenium

Which firefox version is compatible with Selenium 2.42.0 version?

Answer (score 1):

Mozilla version 20 and above. You can see the change log [here](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/java/CHANGELOG).

Comment: errr... the page is not found, @Stanimir